# Spring Boot Records older then 5 years in Oracle

Tags: spring, oracle, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jpql

Query:

```
@Query("select o from Order o where o.creationDate < add_months(sysdate, -60)")
```

`add_months` is not possible in JPA query. How can I get records older then five years?

Comment: Not au fait with Spring Boot but how about standard SQL interval? `sysdate - interval '5' year`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JPQL does not have this kind of function to work with dates.

However, you have two options:

1. Use native SQL with the option `nativeQuery = true`
2. Compute the date on your Java code and pass the result to the query

So, you can use the native SQL adding the attribute `nativeQuery` to the `@Query`:

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "select * from Order o where o.creationDate < add_months(sysdate, -60)")
```

*The use of the `nativeQuery` can be trick when mounting the entity. But this kind of problem is out of the scope of the question.*

The another alternative is still use JPQL, but calculating the old date before call the SQL:

```
LocalDateTime oldDate = LocalDateTime.now().minusMonths(60);
```

Changing the `@Query` to receive the date as parameter:

```
@Query("select o from Order o where o.creationDate < ?1 ")
List<Order> findOldOrders(LocalDateTime oldDate);
```

And calling it:

```
List<Order> orders = repository.findOldOrders(oldDate);
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

`SELECT * FROM Order

WHERE DATEDIFF(YEAR, o.creationDate, GetDate()) >= 5`

or like this

`SELECT * FROM order WHERE o.creationDate < DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 5 YEAR)`

Comment: It seems improbable what looks like SQL Server syntax will run in Oracle database.